# Standard ML - Update global variable within a let-in-end expression?

Tags: scope, standards, global, sml, ml

Is there any way to update a variable binded in global scope within a let-in-end expression?

For example if I have a global variable:

```
val playerScore = 0;
```

and then the function:

```
fun hit (option:int) = 
    if option = 2 then
        printStay(playerScore, dealerScore)
    else 
        let
            val cardDrawn = showCard(hd deck)
            val playerScore = playerScore + getValue(hd deck)
        in 
            print ("You chose to hit\n" ^ cardDrawn ^ "Dealer Score: " ^ Int.toString(dealerScore) ^ "\nPlayer Score: " ^ Int.toString(playerScore) ^ "\n")  
        end;
```

The value of playerScore is updated in the let expression and prints the correct value in the "in" clause but the actual value of playerScore is not saved and resets after this expression finishes.

Is there anyway to retain the value of playerScore on a global level after this expression executes? The problem is that I cannot keep track of the score since it resets to 0 every time.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

A "variable" can never be assigned to in ML. The value of `playerScore`, once initialized, will never change. Period.

In your example, you are declaring a *new* variable called `playerScore` in an inner scope, which hides the outer one. It is a *different* variable, with no relation to the outer one of the same name.

If you want to use mutability, you can use a mutable data structure, the simplest of which is a "ref" cell, which is a single-item mutable cell. You can use the `ref` function to create a ref data structure, the `!` operator to access its contents, and the `:=` operator to change its contents. But mutation only occurs through mutable data structures like `ref`, arrays, etc. Variables cannot be changed.